# How to test a generic function with a lambda function as input in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, tdd

I have a class name `ApiCall` which is something like a bridge between my `ApiService` and Repository , the short version of class is :

```kotlin
class ApiCall {
    fun <T> call(req : suspend() -> T) : LiveData<Result<T>>{
        return liveData {
            try {
                emit(Result.success(req.invoke()))
            }catch (e : Exception){
                emit(Result.failure<T>(Exception("Error")))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My repository is something like this :

```kotlin
class Repository(val apiCall: ApiCall,var apiService : ApiService) {

    fun getListOfPosts() : LiveData<Result<List<Post>>> = apiCall.call(){
        apiService.getListOfPosts()
    }

}
```

and `ApiService`:

```kotlin
interface ApiService {
    @GET("/posts")
    suspend fun getListOfPosts() : List<Post>
}
```

the problem is I want to make a `RepositoryUnitTest` class and in this TDD class I want to have a method that checks if `apiCall.call()` is invoked or not, this is my code:

```kotlin
class RepositoryUnitTest : BaseUnitTest() {

    val apiCall : ApiCall = mock()
    val apiService : ApiService = mock()
    val repository = Repository(apiCall,apiService)

    @Test
    fun `whenever getListOfPosts from repo is called , apiCall must be called too`(){
        repository.getListOfPosts()
        verify(apiCall,times(1)).call<List<Post>>({apiService.getListOfPosts()})
    }

}
```

but it gives me this error and I don't have any clue what is problem, it talks about differences between two functions but as the error mentions, I don't see any differences!

the error:

```
_Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
apiCall.call(
(whenever getListOfPosts from repo is called , apiCall must be called too$1) Function1<kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.util.List<? extends ir.sass.test_sample.Post>>, java.lang.Object>
);
at ir.sass.test_sample.ApiCall.call(ApiCall.kt:8)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
apiCall.call(
    (getListOfPosts$1) Function1<kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.util.List<? extends ir.sass.test_sample.Post>>, java.lang.Object>
);
at ir.sass.test_sample.Repository.getListOfPosts(Repository.kt:8)_
```

Comment: Why would you want to test that, instead of providing an _implementation_ of `ApiService` that returns a sample `List<Post>`, and testing that that's what you get out at the end?

Comment: @LouisWasserman well I'm just learning TDD so i don't what I should test and what I shoudn't , you meant not everything should be tested ?

Comment: Only public behaviors should be tested, not implementations.  Verify that the results are correct, not how they're gotten -- and just because the method is called doesn't even mean the results are correct.

Comment: @LouisWasserman well I watched a course on udemy and the guy first check if the method is called and then in another test check if the response is right. I didn't understand what you meant by " public behaviors not implementations", would you explain it more please?